# Calculating nth fibonacci number modulo m using golden ratio in C

Tags: c, fibonacci, modulo

I am trying to calculate the nth fibonacci number modulo 10^9+7 where n is entered by the user.

I have used the golden ratio to calculate fibonacci numbers.

The following code produces correct results till n=43. But for n>=44, phi goes over 10^9+7 and I start getting unexpected results. Also, n>=44 gives correct result if the modulus is removed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
long double mod=1000000007;

long double power(long double base, long long int expo)
{
    if(base==1  ||  expo==0)
        return 1;
    if(expo&1)
    {
        long double temp = power(base, expo>>1);
        return fmodl(base * fmodl(temp*temp, mod), mod);
    }
    else
    {
        long double temp=power(base, expo>>1);
        return fmodl(temp*temp,mod);
    }
}


int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    long double phi = (1+powl(5, 0.5))/2;
    long double phi_cap = (1 - powl(5, 0.5))/2;
    long double root5 = powl(5, 0.5);
    long long int n;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    long double ans = fmodl(  (power(phi, n) - power(phi_cap, n)) * power(root5,mod-2), mod);
    printf("%.0Lf\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen? Is it wrong to use long double to store irrational numbers?

Thanks

Comment: Question: Is it wrong to use long double to store irrational numbers?
Answer: Yes, it is as they can only be precise to a certain extent. You might want to take a look at libraries like GMP (see [link](https://gmplib.org/)).

Comment: [Modular congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) cannot be applied to rational numbers, only to integers.

Comment: @pytheos: Thanks. But I suppose it should still work for lower values

Comment: @MOehm: Thanks. Does that mean it is not possible to do this using the golden ratio? Could you give an example of when functions like fmodl() and fmod() can be used?

Comment: Why do you want to compute Fibonacci numbers this way? Because you think it's quicker?

Comment: @jdarthenay: Yes. I am trying to use this approach to solve this [question](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ). The math works out in a way that requires products of all values of phi and all values of phi_cap for a given range.

Comment: Use GMP. I greatly recommend it. If I'm not mistaken, they have a fibonnaci function in it.

Comment: Check [the end of this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) for an efficient way to calculate Fibonacci numbers recursively with O(log(n)) complexity.

Comment: @jdarthenay Thanks. I am aware of the non-recursive version of this approach. But I am looking for a way using the golden ratio as this is what I need to solve the mentioned question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [closed form expression for the n'th Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) is

> F<sub>n</sub>   =   φ<sup>n</sup> / √5   -   ψ<sup>n</sup> / √5

where

> φ = 1/2 + √5/2 ≅ 1.6180339887
>   ψ = 1/2 - √5/2 = φ - 1 ≅ 0.6180339887

Since the substracted part in F<sub>n</sub> is always less than one half, we can calculate [F<sub>n</sub> via rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding) towards zero (or, towards negative infinity, or `floor()`, since F<sub>n</sub> is nonnegative for n ≥ 0):

> F<sub>n</sub> = ⌊ φ<sup>n</sup> / √5 ⌋ = floor( φ<sup>n</sup> / √5 )

If we are interested in F<sub>n</sub> modulo M, M ≥ 2, we need to observe the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) affects the above formula. Note that the expression *"expr MOD M"* is typically computed using [`fmod(expr, M)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmod.3.html) in C.

We can apply the [property of modular multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Remainders): for positive reals *a*, *b*, and *m*, (*a* mod *m*)(*b* mod *m*) = (*a* *b* mod *m*). The floor operation is not affected. Here, *a* = φ<sup>n</sup>, and *b* = 1/√5. This means we can simplify the expression

> F<sub>n</sub> MOD M = ⌊ φ<sup>n</sup> / √5 ⌋ MOD M

into

> F<sub>n</sub> MOD M = ⌊ ( φ<sup>n</sup> MOD (M√5) ) / √5 ⌋

Here, we can apply [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), noting that the modulus at this point is not by integer M, but by *M·√5*.

In other words, if we have a function that does an integer power of a floating-point value using modular exponentiation with floating-point modulus, say

```
double pow_mod(double base, unsigned int exponent, double modulus);
```

we can calculate the n'th Fibonacci number F<sub>n</sub> modulo m using

```
#define PHI    1.61803398874989484820458683436563811772
#define SQRT5  2.236067977499789696409173668731276235441;

double fn_mod_m;
unsigned int n, m;

fn_mod_m = floor(pow_mod(PHI, n, SQRT5 * (double)m) / SQRT5);
```

The [right-to-left method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) is an excellent candidate for the modular exponentiation here.

Comment: Could you explain how you went from mod M to mod Mroot5? I tried using [this method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Using_Euler.27s_theorem) but it probably works only for integers?

Comment: @raksh93: I added the explanation to the answer; because `(a mod m)*(b mod m) = (a*b) mod m`. The floor operation is not affected, because it just substracts a small value (less than one) from the result, and moving the modulo operation does not affect the value to be floor()ed at all. As to modular exponentiation, you really should use the [right-to-left method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method), instead: the Wikipedia page even has pseudocode to show you how. Or you can use the memory-efficient method, pseudocode just before on that same page.

Comment: Modular arithmetic doesn't work out quite well for real numbers such as PHI and SQRT5.